# p2p transfers over local network in javascript

Tags: javascript, p2p

Would it be possible to have p2p data transfers over a local network using javascript without having the users run anything on their computers besides the website? I wish to create a game that allows you to connect to devices on your network to play.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: web socket, is that what you meant?

Comment: I guess at the moment just a web chat that allows for you to talk to other people on your LAN network

Comment: Yes, it is possible, there are quite a number of frameworks around, but you should do your homework. Its time-consuming because of many dead, outdated, alpha or dead-end projects. Personally I'm interested in internet-wide decentralized P2P apps, and my eye fell on [Dat Project](https://datproject.org) and its [hypercore](https://github.com/mafintosh/hypercore) protocol.

Comment: You could start with [awesome-p2p](https://github.com/kgryte/awesome-peer-to-peer) and [p2pfoundation](http://wiki.p2pfoundation.net/Main_Page) (many resources, bit of a search needed)

Comment: BTW in your case with local networks a [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/) solution may be sufficient